# control input text from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know if it's possible to control an input text from the controller in rails, for example I want to clean an input text after I did some validations and also request focus on that input text, like this:

```
if params[:pswd] == params[:pswd2]
     flash = change_pswd('root', params[:oldPswd], params[:pswd])
     if not flash.key?(:error)
        redirect_to logged_in_path
     end
  else
     flash[:error] = "New password doesn't match."
     #here i want to clean the input text
     #request focus for that input
     render :changePassword
  end
```

Comment: No, you can't control a rendered page from controller. You can, however, control what's being rendered (that is, choose to render input text with or without text). But once it's rendered - it's out of controller's reach.

Answer (score 0):

**in changePassword**

```
<%= text_field_tag :oldPswd, ""  %>
<%= text_field_tag :pswd, ""  %>
<%= text_field_tag :pswd2, ""  %>
```

see [text_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag)

Answer (score 0):

To this requirement, I think it would be more convenient to handle with AJAX.